# Basic idea of shadow mapping using forward rendering (glsl 1.2)

Tags: opengl, glsl

Well, let's see if I understand the idea behind the shadow mapping.

1. create a number of FBOs that lights (maximum 8)
2. create same number of depth textures (shadow maps) for those FBOs
3. for every FBO perform off-screen rendering (render to texture, drawing the scene from the point of view of each of the lights, maximum 8 times)

Is this correct?

But how do I render the final scene with shadows then? Do I have to render the whole scene for each shadow map?

```
int main() {

    //Number of lights = 8;

    glUseProgram(programa);
      glUniformli(shadowM0,4);
      glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT0);
      //Draw Escene?
    
      glUniformli(shadowM1,5);
      glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT1);
      //Draw Escene?
    
      glUniformli(shadowM2,6);
      glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE6);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT2);
      //Draw Escene?
      
      ...
    glUseProgram(0);
  
    ...  
}
```

And if not, how should I do the final render of the scene?

Would appreciate any corrections to the above steps in case I missed something or any recommendations for improving the idea using forward rendering.

Comment: An omnidirectional light would require multiple shadow maps.

Comment: Okay, only I use point lights. But then this code is right? Could I use less FBOs or less texture objects for the same number of lights (8)? Thank you.

Comment: A point light does shine in every direction, yes?

Comment: It is true. Sorry I mean directional lights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way.

Simplest solution would be - use only one shadowmap/FBO

```
foreach light {
  render shadowmap;
  foreach object {
    calculate lighting for given light with given shadowmap;
    additively blend with framebuffer;
  }
}
```

By additive I mean `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);`

Other way is to calculate many lights at once, but it introduces other problems, like if shader expects to calculate 8 lights, but you only have 7? And if you have 16, you'll need to draw twice (with additive blend, as usual).

```
glUseProgram(programa);
  glUniformli(shadowM0,4);
  glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT0);

  glUniformli(shadowM1,5);
  glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT1);

  glUniformli(shadowM2,6);
  glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE6);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthT2);

  // ... <set all other shadowmaps>

  // now draw. once. and use all shadowmaps you've set in shader
```

Comment: Mmmmmh. Is not that almost the same as the example I wrote? foreach shadowmap{draw escene}

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you've tried to achieve when you binding different textures to different slots, while drawing scene in between... It makes no sense. If it would be one texture slot - well, maybe, impossible to say without seeing shader code.

Comment: Do not you say anything the message title?

Comment: What?.. It is getting hard to understand you. All I'm saying is that you doing it wrong. Either bind all textures at once and calculate many light sources at once in shader (this will require only one draw, if you don't have too many lights), or use one texture slot for shadow map. Code you have in question is abomination that gets a bit from both approaches; even if it works, it shouldn't.

Comment: Okay, so I asked for help. To fix the idea of ​​multiple shadowmaps.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would tell me if I'm okay, and even if this idea can be optimized. Thanks.

Comment: Already told you, it's not ok. My previous comment have detailed description about what should be done. If you don't use all your shadowmaps at once - then you need only one. But it is clear that we speaking different languages and sure as hell don't understand eachother.

Comment: It is true. I apologize because I did not make myself clear. The code I wrote is if I use the 8 lights simultaneously. So it would be correct? Thanks.